# C# code to delete lines in excel

Tags: c#, excel

Please find the below C# coding to delete lines from excel.
I am facing the error

> "the type or namespace name ExcelFile,ExcelWorksheet could not be
>   found"

```
public void Main()
{
     ExcelFile excel = ExcelFile.Load("Sample.xlsx");
     ExcelWorksheet sheet = excel.Worksheets[0];
     sheet.Rows.Remove(4);
     excel.Save("Sample.xlsx");
     Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorksheet ; 
using the namespace throws "; expected" error

Any guidance?

Comment: Have you added a reference to the interop assemblies? `ExcelFile` &      `ExcelWorksheet` are not types within that namespace, where are they supposed to come from?  The error with `using` is a simple syntax error that is not solvable without seeing your code.

Comment: As alternative you can consider using EPPlus http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: The reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel was added.  I am not sure with C# coding . My objective is to delete the first 4 lines in an excel sheet.Any help with the code